# How to control the appearance of different parts of a curve in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots

I want to plot a curve in beamer so that the different parts of the curve appear one by one.

I have indicated the different parts in different color and used the command \pause so that they would appear one by one, but it does not work. Below is the code I have used:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage{etex}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\newenvironment<>{varexampleblock}[2][1.0\textwidth]{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}%
    \setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}%
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=example text}%
    \usebeamertemplate{block example begin}}
  {\par%
  \usebeamertemplate{block example end}%
    \end{actionenv}}
    
\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}
    
\begin{document}

{   
    \setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\small}

\begin{frame}[shrink = 20]
\frametitle{Sketching Curves} \pause

\begin{varexampleblock}[20cm]{Example} \pause

$f(x)=x^2(x-1)(x-3)$

\pause

\textbf{Solution:} \pause

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=-7, ymax=7, axis lines=middle,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
title={$y=f(x)$}
]
\addplot[ color=black, samples=100, domain=-4:0.5]{x^2*(x-1)*(x-3)};

\addplot[ color=blue, samples=100, domain=0.5:2, draw on=<2->]{x^2*(x-1)*(x-3)};

\addplot[ color=red, samples=100, domain=2:5, draw on=<3->]{x^2*(x-1)*(x-3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{varexampleblock}

\end{frame}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please give the complete and compilable code that includes the necessary packages for this example to be minimal.

Comment: Hi, I now have added the full code. Regards, Adrian

Comment: @AdrianKorban No, that is not the full code :) If you try your example you'll get an error saying that `varexampleblock` is undefined, because your example doesn't include it's definition.

Comment: Sorry - now I have added the complete code. Sorry, it is my first time posting something on here, and I got a bit confused.

Answer (score 5):

You can perhaps use the features of the `overlay-beamer-styles` library, provided by the package `aobs-tikz`. In the example below I used explicit slide numbers, e.g. `draw on=<2->`, which means that plot is drawn only for the second slide onwards. Using incremental overlay specifications (`<+->`) didn't seemt to work, but I didn't try with your complete code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=-7, ymax=7, axis lines=middle,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
title={$y=f(x)$}
]
\addplot[ color=black, samples=100, domain=-4:0.5]{x^2*(x-1)*(x-3)};

\addplot[ color=blue, samples=100, domain=0.5:2, draw on=<2->]{x^2*(x-1)*(x-3)};

\addplot[ color=red, samples=100, domain=2:5, draw on=<3->]{x^2*(x-1)*(x-3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time and the answer. I have tried it, but it did not work - I have edited the code (at the top) so that it is a complete code now.

Comment: @AdrianKorban It does work I think, but you need to adjust it slightly. In your example there are 4 `\pause`s before the diagram, meaning that the diagram appears in the 5th slide. Hence, the second and third part of the graph should appear in slide 6 and 7. As I wrote in my answer, `<2->` means that element appears in the *second* slide. So you need to change `<2->` to `<6->` and `<3->` to `<7->`.  You could use `<+->` for both, but that doesn't quite work, I get two slides with just the first part of the graph.

Comment: Thank you!! This now works perfectly!